# Generator usage about yield

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

My code:

```
function wrapper(generatorFunction) {
  return function (...args) {
    let generatorObject = generatorFunction(...args);
    generatorObject.next();
    return generatorObject;
  };
}

const wrapped = wrapper(function* () {
  console.log(`First input: ${yield}`);
  return 'DONE';
});

wrapped();
```

I have a question regarding why the web console isn't printing `First input`. Although `yield` returns undefined.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  This looks hopelessly more complicated than needed for any purpose I can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you do next(), it will execute till the first yield.

```js
function wrapper(generatorFunction) {
    return function (...args) {
        let generatorObject = generatorFunction(...args);
        generatorObject.next(); // Will Print till yield keyword => First Yield Call
        console.log('About to pass in a value to First Input');
        let done = generatorObject.next(42); // Will Print and Bring the next yielded value => First Input 22
        console.log(done);
        return generatorObject;
    };
}

wrapped = wrapper(function* () {
    console.log('First Yield Call');
    console.log(`First input: ${yield}`);
    return 'DONE';
});

wrapped();
```

Comment: so,if  `yeild` not return value,it can't be printed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. The use of return in a Generator function will just treat as the last yield, that means it will give {value: return_value, done: true}

Comment: I mean when the program firstly call next method, it doesn't return any value.so the browser can't print "first input".My question is why can't print "first input" when firstly call?

Comment: Its simple, for the first next call it will execute all the code before first yield keyword and what ever you have on the right side of yield it will return as a result to the first next call. The second time you call next you will continue you you left off, you can even pass data into the next call and you can hold that data in a variable and use it in the Generator Function body.